# VS2005 "Add New Item..." dialog - default item

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2005, development-environment

After installing a third-party SDK, it very discourteously makes one if its templates the default item in "Add New Item..." dialog in Visual Studio 2005. This is also the case for all other similar dialogs - "Add Class...", "Add User Control..." etc.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

You may have to manually modify the SortOrder on the Item templates yourself.  You can do this by following these directions:

1) Find the Item Template(s)

Item Templates for VS2005 are stored in the following locations:

```
 (Installed Templates) <VisualStudioInstallDir>\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\Language\Locale\
 (Custom Templates) My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Templates\ItemTemplates\Language\
```

2) Open the template zip file to modify the .vstemplate file.

Each Item Template is stored in a .zip file, so you will need to open the zip file that pertains to the template you want to modify.

Open the template's .vstemplate file and find the SortOrder property under the TemplateData section.  The following is a sample file:

<TemplateData>
     <Name>SomeITem</Name>
     <Description>Description</Description>
     <ProjectType>>CSharp</ProjectType>
     **<SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>**
     <DefaultName></DefaultName>
     <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
   </TemplateData>

Modify the SortOrder value using the following rules:

- The default value is 100, and all values must be multiples of 10.
- The SortOrder element is ignored for user-created templates. All user-created templates are sorted alphabetically.
- Templates that have low sort order values appear in either the New Project or New Add Item dialog box before templates that have high sort order values.

Once you've made edits to the template definitions you'll need to open a command prompt and navigate to the directory that contains devenv.exe, and type "devenv /setup". This presumably rebuilds some internal settings and until you do this you won't see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've just noticed this file on my PC:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\VCNewItems\NewItems.vsdir
```

It's a text file, so you could check if the offending third-party stuff is in there.

Answer (score -1):

Try looking at the registry under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
```

I see some relevant entries on my machine under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0
```

for VS2008.

Comment: This unfortunately does not do the trick. None of the entries seem to reference the item which appears as the dialog's default.

Comment: Is there a DefaultProjectTreeSelection, or DefaultProjItemListSelection there?